# Does vsftpd requires apache to work?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx, ftp

My friend and I have two identical CentOS 5 VPSs from the same hosting provider, his using Apache and mine using Nginx. He followed [this tutorial](http://www.noob2geek.com/linux/setup-vsftpd-debian-ubuntu/) and vsftpd worked. He tried to install vsftpd on my VPS using the same procedure and it did not work.

Does vsftpd requires Apache to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Vsftpd does **not** require Apache to work.